# Segmentation fault when Connect to MySQL in python 3.5.1 on AIX 6

Tags: python, mysql, segmentation-fault

I tried to do following tasks:
1 Compile Python 3.5.1 source use GCC 4.2.0 on AIX 6.0;
2 Use Python 3.5.1 do my work including connect and uses mysql databae;
once I tried this tasks,I can compile python 3.5.1 source successful,and doing something well except connect and uses database;

```
$/usr/local/bin/python3.5
Python 3.5.1 (default, Aug 12 2016, 15:48:31) 
[GCC 4.2.0] on aix6
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> dir(sys.path)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

and then I tried install PyMySQL-0.7.6 witch I was working well on Linux and Windows,and it install successful,but unfortunately,when I tried to use it to connect to MySQL database,it gave me 'Segmentation fault(coredump)' error and it abort python automatic;

```
>>> import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host='150.17.31.113',user='sywu',password='sywu',db='sydb',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor);>>> connection = pymysql.connect(host='150.17.31.113',user='sywu',password='sywu',db='sydb',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor);
Segmentation fault(coredump)
$
```

again and again,it always like this,I had read core file,it contains unhuman readable contents,and I can't figure out the problem was, since I can't do it with pymysql,I tried install mysql-connector-python 2.1.3,it install successful,but I got 'Illegal instruction(coredump)' error and it abort python automatic,

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> cnx=mysql.connector.connect(user='sywu',password='sywu',host='150.17.31.113',database='sydb')
Illegal instruction(coredump)
$
```

does anyone to do this on aix successful,any help?

Comment: MySql is written in C++, plus it uses cmake -- it is very hard to compile it on AIX. You could use GNU/linux where all these components work 'out of the box'

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used AIX but from the code snippet, I could figure that from https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/example.py, the parameter is `passwd` not `password`.

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='mysql')
```

Also, in the same library: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL, look at the example. May be it can help you out.

Comment: `connection = pymysql.connect(host='150.17.31.113',user='sywu',password='sywu',db='sydb',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor);`  
or
`connection = pymysql.connect(host='150.17.31.113',user='sywu',passwd='sywu',db='sydb',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor); `
both way worked well in version PyMySQL-0.7.3 and PyMySQL-0.7.6  in Python 3.5.1 on Linux and Windows

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem when trying to connect to mysql database from python 3.6 using mysql.connector ....

just getting core dump segmentation fault
after working around for decent time then i just placed

from mysql.connector import (
MySQLConnection as db,
errorcode,
Error
)

in the first line..
this worked for me !!!!!